# How do I change the port I run a play application with using gradle?

Tags: gradle, playframework

I recently discovered the play plugin for gradle and would like to know how to configure the port the application runs on.

I've read the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/play_plugin.html) page on the gradle site but still find myself a little confused. So if someone would like to just like to spell it out for me that would be great.

Kind Regards

Will

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playrun has an [httpPort](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.play.tasks.PlayRun.html#org.gradle.play.tasks.PlayRun:httpPort) property you can use, something like this should work

```
tasks.withType(PlayRun) {
    httpPort = 9999
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic solution would be to use command line parameters with **-P** (project property option)

```
tasks.withType(PlayRun) {
    if (project.hasProperty("httpPort")) {
        httpPort = Integer.parseInt(project.httpPort)
    } else {
        httpPort = 9000 //default value
    }
}
```

and then run gradle

```
gradle runPlayBinary -PhttpPort="9876"
```

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<org.gradle.playframework.tasks.PlayRun> {
  httpPort.set(9001)
}
```